# Flex - how to display scroll-able text and capture a click/focus event to allow new text to be added?

Tags: apache-flex, events, textarea, flash-builder

In flex (flash builder 4.6), I have a s:TextArea box which I have set as editable="false".  This allows me to display the text to the user, and the text box is scrollable (but they are not able to edit the existing text).

I added a button to my form that pops-up a simple custom component that allows the user to enter some text and then by catching a custom event I add that text to my TextArea.

That works, but I also want the user to be able to click on the actual text area to pop-up my custom text input dialog.

I tried adding a FocusIn event handler.   This works, but the problem is that FocusIn seems to also be thrown when I am modifying the text.   So when the user clicks, my dialog opens, but then when they click to close my dialog, it just pops right back open...

SO, I think I either need some way to know whether this was actually a single mouse click on the text area, or maybe there is a different approach?

Comment: Why not just listen for a click event on the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, RIAstar was correct - I swear I tried the click event and it did not work properly, but I just tried it again and it seems to work great.  Thanks!